# How to show Updated values of UITableViewCell from another method ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I declared globally

```
  NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
```

and here is my didselectmethod

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
   UIAlertView *loAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Are you sure you want to redeem?" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];
   loAlert.tag  = 10;
   [loAlert show];
   selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
  }
```

After selecting row i am showing alert

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex 
 {
      if(alertView.tag == 10)
     {
         if(buttonIndex == 0)
         {
           [self redeemOfferService];
         }
     }
 }
```

**Then calling redeemOfferService, in this method i am facing problem**

```
- (void)redeemOfferService
{

   OffersBoughtCellTableViewCell * selectedCell1 = [offersTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath]; 

  NSLog(@"%@ ************",   selectedCell1.quantity.text);
   // for e.g. selected cell's quantity is 0 (here i can see selected cell quantity)
   i want to change and update here as follow  

   selectedCell1.quantity.text = @"Quantity  : 5";

  // after this i can see quantity in my cell is 5 but 
     when i scroll values are again showing from

  cellForRowAtIndexPath i want to show updated value on cell,
  how to do this ?
}
```

For more details here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  OffersBoughtCellTableViewCell  *cell = (OffersBoughtCellTableViewCell *) 
  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"offersCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  OfferDetail * offerDetailObj=[[OfferDetail alloc]init];

// OfferDetail, OffersBoughtDetails are NSObject class 
// @property (nonatomic, strong) OfferDetail *offerObj;& OffersBoughtDetails * selectedOfferBoughtObj;
// and @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *offersBought;

  offerDetailObj=[self.listOfOffers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  OffersBoughtDetails * offerBoughtObj=[self.offerObj.offersBought objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  selectedOfferBoughtObj=offerBoughtObj;
  cell.quantity.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Quantity  : %@",offerBoughtObj.quantity];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you scroll to your changed cell again, `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` get invoked, but your data would not change,`cell.quantity.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Quantity  : %@",offerBoughtObj.quantity];`, so your cell's quantity still shows what your data model offerBoughtObj is.

Since iOS uses MVC, a solution is you change your data model, and then reflect your model changes to your view.

```
- (void)redeemOfferService {
    OffersBoughtDetails * offerBoughtObj=[self.offerObj.offersBought objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath];
    // change offerBoughtObj to the value you want
    offerBoughtObj.quantity = whateveryoulike;
    // reload your tableview
    [tablview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Comment: Yup...! thanks :) worked ..i updated as u said  OffersBoughtDetails * offerBoughtObj=[self.offerObj.offersBought objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];
                 offerBoughtObj.quantity = @"5";
                 [_offersTableView reloadData];
                 [_offersTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
 in redeemOfferService.

Answer (score 0):

As far As I understand your problem after selecting a Cell You want to remove that cell from UITableView.

To do this put all your UITable data in NSMutableArray

And In your  `- (void)redeemOfferService` method after doing all task 
just remove that selected object like:

```
      [dataArray removeObject:@"selectedObject"];
```

And reload the table Data

```
      [tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the source of the table, the `offerDetailObj` in your case, so in `- (void)redeemOfferService` methods, fetch the data from the array and get the selected object, update it's value and save it again to your array. I think this should work:

```
- (void)redeemOfferService
{

   OffersBoughtCellTableViewCell * selectedCell1 = [offersTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath]; 

  NSLog(@"%@ ************",   selectedCell1.quantity.text);
   // for e.g. selected cell's quantity is 0 (here i can see selected cell quantity)
   //i want to change and update here as follow  

   selectedCell1.quantity.text = @"Quantity  : 5";

  //Update your source array to the correct value
  offerDetailObj=[self.listOfOffers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  OffersBoughtDetails * offerBoughtObj=[self.offerDetailObj.offersBought objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  OffersBoughtDetails.quantity = 5;
  [offerDetailObj replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:offerBoughtObj];
  self.listOfOffers replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:offerDetailObj];

}
```

Your Array should be mutable so you can add/remove/replace object from it, means that your `listOfOffers` and `offersBought` should be `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your alertViewDelegate method you should set selectetdIndexPath to nil if the user selects NO

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
   if(alertView.tag == 10)
  {
     if(buttonIndex == 0)
     {
       [self redeemOfferService];
     }
      else
        selectedIndexPath = nil;
  }
}
```

and in your redeemOffService you should reload cell

```
- (void)redeemOfferService
{

  OffersBoughtCellTableViewCell * selectedCell1 = [offersTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath]; 

  NSLog(@"%@ ************",   selectedCell1.quantity.text);
// for e.g. selected cell's quantity is 0 (here i can see selected cell quantity)
i want to change and update here as follow  

selectedCell1.quantity.text = @"Quantity  : 5";
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

selectedIndexPath = nil;
}
```

Hope this helps :D